# How to remove global menu from gnome shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, appmenu

Maybe asking my question in this way was incorrect. when I switch into Gnome session and use a theme that have a transparent dock, in top left of screen there is global-menu for nautilus.

I edited one custom theme and change #panel height to a short height, I can use global-menu.

maybe it's a simple bug in 11.10 beta2 release, but how can I remove this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with gnome3-shell (top taskbar)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73482/problem-with-gnome3-shell-top-taskbar)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [bug in Nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/826771). Currently there is no known fix other than to disable Nautilus drawing the desktop:

> The temporary solution I have found it's to disable the 'Have the filemanager handle the desktop' option. You can use gnome-tweak-tool to do that. The downside is that the desktop icons won't show anymore.

Comment: thanks, I didn't store anything on my desktop =)

Answer (score 1):

you can also solve the bug and still have shortcuts on you desktop by removing global menu with

`sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt`

This however will also have the same effect on your unity session.