# Problem with gnome3-shell (top taskbar)

Tags: gnome, taskbar

I install gnome-shell and Zukitwo-theme. The upper taskbar it is transparent but behind is a  bar how can get rid off it. 
Do I need this bar?
See the image!!

[image]

Comment: This is a known bug on Launchpad: [Bug #826771](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/826771)

Comment: I suggest you check out this bug [Bug#826771](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/826771) as pointed out in another comment and if this is the same as the you have mark it as affecting you too. The more people a bug affects the higher the priority developers give to fixing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have 2 options.

1. disable the global menu in unity. `sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-qt`
2. in gnome tweak turn off the option  `have file mangaer handle
   desktop` if you don't mind not having icons on the desktop.

then, log out and login. or hit `alt+f2` and enter `r` to restart the shell.

Comment: Yes I found it by my self it was "on" the "have file mangaer handle desktop" in gnome-tweak
Thnx

Comment: Thanks, option 1 solved my problem. Although it did not go away after `alt+f2`, but it did after a restart.