# Gnome-shell displays application menus in its panel

Tags: 11.10, gnome

Yesterday, I installed gnome-shell and managed to get it working after a little bit of trouble. Now I'm getting a kind of weird problem, which an image will explain better than my words can: [image: http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/5287/screenshotat20111031174.png]

As you can see, Firefox's menu (just an example, it happens with every application) displays in the gnome-shell panel (same behavior as Unity has). Also, it seems to be under the panel, since you can't hover or click on it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with gnome3-shell (top taskbar)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73482/problem-with-gnome3-shell-top-taskbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install Gnome Tweak Tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then open it and turn the option on Desktop: "Have file manager handle desktop" off.