# Application Menus File,View, etc missing in Gnome-fallback

Tags: gnome, themes, menu

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and i like it but Gnome 3 slows my pc too much so i'm trying to use the Gnome-fallback which is a bit faster.

So far everything works like Gnome 2 except that the Application menus are not showing in any application nor even Nautilus and i hope there's a way to fix this.

[image: My Home Folder. No Menus are there]
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possibly this Q&A is your issue?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/73482/problem-with-gnome3-shell-top-taskbar

Comment: @fossfreedom i dont have appmenu installed

Comment: ok - add what you have just tried into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after alot of searching and trying i found a solution to show the hidden application menus in my system.

**Please Note:** The original gnome-shell, without being tweaked, does not have this issue.

The issue mainly is caused by *GlobalMenu* which appears to be Not Supported under the *Gnome3-fallback* mode just yet.

So what I did was Disabling the GlobalMenu and got my Application menus back once again, and here's how i did it:

First, we need *dconf-editor* so we're going to install *dconf-tools*

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

after installing, Press ALT+F2 and Type *dconf-editor* and press Enter.

now navigate to *org/globalmenu* and uncheck *enabled*.

You may either log out and log back in or restart your system and the Application menus will be ready to be used once again.

[image]

Comment: hi i dont see that menu in dconf in 14.04. Do you know whereit might be located?